# How do I reference the current instance in the c'tor in F#?

Tags: exception, f#, actor

*Questions (3 of them that are related) are bolded below.*

I'm trying to create a F# class -- I need to consume it without referencing F#'s assembly from C#.

I have code like this:

```
type ReceiverExceptionEventArgs(ex:Exception) =
    inherit EventArgs()
    member this.Exception = ex

type ExceptionRaised = delegate of obj * ReceiverExceptionEventArgs -> unit

type Receiver( ... ) =

  let error  = new Event<ExceptionRaised, ReceiverExceptionEventArgs>()

  let a = new Actor<...>(fun inbox -> ...)   

  [<CLIEvent>]
  member __.Error = error.Publish

  /// Starts the receiver which starts the consuming from the service bus
  /// and creates the queue if it doesn't exist
  member x.Start () =
    logger.InfoFormat("start called for queue '{0}'", desc)
    a.Post Start
```

I'd like to add this after `let a = new Actor...`:

```
do a.Error.Add(fun ex -> error.Trigger(this, new ReceiverExceptionEventArgs(ex)))
```

**But I don't have a reference to 'this' on the above line... How would I do it idiomatically in F#?**

*As a further complication,* the actor is starting a number of asynchronous computations that are basically loops; these computations return unit, so I can't just do:

```
let startPairsAsync pairs token =
  async {
    for Pair(mf, rs) in pairs do
      for r in rs do 
        match Async.Start(Async.Catch(r |> worker), token) with
        | Choice1Of2 () -> ()
        | Choice2Of2 ex -> error.Trigger(null, new ReceiverExceptionEventArgs(ex)) }
```

because `worker r` is `Async<unit>`, so **I get `This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but was here 'Choice1of2<'a, 'b>'` on the first pattern match.**

---

*Digression:*

Is the idea that I create actors for each worker also? I'd like to have code that is similar to how erlang does 'supervisors' because what I'm working with may fail arbitrarily at almost any point (network)... Supervisors is outside the scope of this question; but **would I get better idiomatic exception handling with mutliple Actors rather than Async.Catch?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `this`, use

```
type MyClass(args) as this =
```

in the declaration to bind `this` inside the constructor.  (You can use any identifier you like.)

(See also

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/the-basic-syntax-of-f-classes-interfaces-and-members/

)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question involving asynchronous workflow, I don't fully understand your code, but if you're trying to start some asynchronous computations and handle exceptions that may happen while executing them, it is a lot easier to use `try ... with` inside asynchronous workflow instead of `Async.Catch`. Something like this might be better:

```
let startPairsAsync pairs token = 
  let work = 
    [ for Pair(mf, rs) in pairs do 
        for r in rs do  
          // Produce asynchronous computation that is 
          // protected using a try .. with block
          yield async { 
            try do! worker r 
            with e -> error.Trigger(null, new ReceiverExceptionEventArgs(ex)) } ]
    // Compose them to run all computations in parallel
    |> Async.Parallel

  // Run composed computation with a cancellation token
  Async.Start(work, token)
```

Comment: In general; would you recommend using standard exception handling with actors? Isn't there a more coarse-grained way of doing it?

Comment: @Henrik - I'm not sure what you mean when you refer to "actors"? Do you mean the F# `MailboxProcessor` type (also called agents) or asynchronous workflows? In general, using `try .. with` in `async { .. }` blocks should give you all you need. Note the exceptions propagate automatically, so this is not too fine-grained if you wrap the whole computation in a handler.

Comment: Hi, yes, I mean MailboxProcessor - can I link them together like I would with actors?